# How to upload a file in Grails 3

Tags: grails, spring-boot

Grails 2 had a plugin for that, there also used to be

```
request.getFile
```

method. There is no method like this in Grails 3 as far as I can see, or a plugin. 
I tried using

```
request.getInputStream
```

But this one is always empty. Other thing I tried was by using Spring-boot way of handling Uploads, but this one relies on

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
```

It cannot be used in Grails, controllers there do not allow parameters to be defined this way AFAIK.
How to upload files in Grails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is

```
request.getFile(fileName)
```

in Grails 3 as well.  It was just not displayed in autofill in my IDE for some reason (the rest of the request methods like getParameters or isPost are displayed correctly).